# Bayes Theorem, intuitive analysis

Tags: probability

$P(A | B)=P(A \cap B)/P(B)$

**Observation one:** By dividing by the total outcomes of B we are assuming that events in $P(A \cap B)$ are equally-likely

**Observation two:** The commonly, sighted initutation for conditional probability is 'Assume B already happened and calculate probability of A'. To me this bit 'flimsy'.  I like to think about conditional probabiity as follows: "Constrain the possiblties in A by removing outcomes that are impossible due to the constraint/filter/condition B"

$P(A \cap B) = P(B \cap A)$

$P(B \cap A) = P(B | A) P(A)$

$P(A | B) = P(B | A)P(A)/P(B)$

$P(B | A) = P(B)P(A | B)/P(A)$

**Observation three**: since in my defination of conditional probability I am assuming equally likely events, doesn't that also mean that Bayes rule assumes equally likely events? What happens when this is not so?

**My question is:** are my observations correct and if not, why?

Answer (score 1):

Your second set of observations is correct.  However, observations one and three exhibit a slight misconception.  You don't need to look at $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ as consisting of sums of probabilities of equally likely "events."

For example, let $X$ and $Y$ be iid standard normal variates on $(0,1)$.  Then if $A$ is "$X > 0.5$", $A$ is in no obvious way to view $A$ as the sum of equally likely "events." 
Nor is $B$ defined as "$X-Y <1.0$.  Yet Bayes theorem still holds:

$$P(A|B) = P(A\wedge B)/P(B)$$